# SAS PROC IMPORT with Dynamic Named Ranges

Tags: excel, sas, named-ranges

I have a workbook containing database information split into various tabs that I want to import into SAS for further manipulation.

The dimensions of these database tables vary from tab to tab and in addition, there might be further changes to the dimensions of the table throughout the tenure of this project.

As such, I've set up dynamic named ranges in every tab such that it picks up the exact dimensions I require i.e. My named range `TBL_SHEET1`

```
=OFFSET(SHEET1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(SHEET1!$A:$A),COUNTA(SHEET1!$1:$1)-2)
```

Now the SAS issue is that when I use the proc import code, it does not seem to think these named ranges "exist" and returns a failure message in the log.

Is there a way around this? Or just a limitation in the way SAS communicates with Excel?

(As a side note, the reason why I am not just importing the entire tab is because there are some extra columns to the right which I want to exclude from my import)

My SAS import code:

```
proc import 
out= rwork.SHEET1
datafile = "C:\My User\Sample.xlsx"
dbms= excel replace;
range=TBL_SHEET1.;
getnames=yes;
run;
```

Comment: Please provide your `proc import` code and the content of the failure message.

Comment: I looked into this a few years ago and discovered the same thing, namely that SAS only recognizes simple named ranges, not dynamic ones.  This isn't likely a fault with SAS, but more with the engine that enables the 2 pieces of software to communicate with each other.  I think I ended up creating a fixed named range that was bigger than I'd ever need, just for importing into SAS

Comment: What engine are you using? Are you using one like EXCEL that calls microsoft code? or the new XLSX engine that can run on non windows operating systems?

Comment: @Tom running on SAS 9.3, Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Adding your code will really help. However, if I understood your question correct, the problem is with importing named ranges. Here's an example on how to import user defined named range into SAS.

In the example below, I am selecting Range `A1:C7` and naming the range as `Test`

[image]

Now, to import the names range `Test` into SAS,

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= WANT
DATAFILE= "C:\Desktop\Test.xls"
DBMS=XLS REPLACE;
RANGE="Test";
GETNAMES=YES;
RUN;
```

In the above code, `Range` tells SAS to import data from excel under named range `Test`. You can also automate the code and import multiple excel sheets with dynamic name range into `SAS`.

For example, I have multiple sheets in an `Excel` which I want to import into `SAS`, I'll use the following code to bring the `spreadsheets` to `SAS`.

```
# Assigning Library #

Libname Test "C:\Desktop\Test.xls";

# Creating a table to select sheet names in above library #

Proc sql;
create table test_excel as 
select * 
from dictionary.tables
where libname="Test" ;
Quit;

# Assigning count and Sheet names to macros#

## Sheet names ##

Proc sql;
select memname into: list seperated by '*'
from test_excel 
;
quit;

## Number of sheets ##

Proc sql;
select count(memname) into:count 
from test_excel 
;
quit;

# Macro to import  #

options mprint;
%macro import;
%do i=1 %to &count;
%let var=%scan(&list,&i,*);

PROC IMPORT OUT= %substr(&var,1,%length(&var)-1)
 DATAFILE= "C:\Desktop\Test.xls"
 DBMS=EXCEL REPLACE;
 RANGE="&var";
 GETNAMES=YES;
RUN;
 %end;
%mend import;

%import ;
```

I hope this is clear.

Comment: The problem is that I don't believe SAS recognizes dynamic named ranges in Excel, only fixed ranges.  Try changing your named range to a dynamic one, along the lines of that detailed by the OP, and you'll find it won't appear in SAS

Comment: Yep, @Longfish has my issue down exactly right. Thanks for your response anyway Praneeth Kumar

Comment: No problem. Thanks so much for clarification @Longfish

Answer (score 0):

I replicated the problem and also can't import a **dynamic** (not fixed) range from Excel. It doesn't work on either `EXCEL` or `XLSX` engines.

If you need a quick solution and don't necessarily have to use Excel ranges, here is a workaround for the problem:

1. Allocate one sheet's cell, e.g `A1` for storing what you currently store in the dynamic range `TBL_sheet1`, i.e. the range of cells to import.

[image]

2. Execute `proc import` only to import this range of cells:

   ```
   PROC IMPORT DATAFILE="C:\test.xlsx" DBMS=xlsx out=work.x
   replace;
   getnames=no;
   RANGE="Sheet1$A1:A1";
   RUN;
   ```
3. Next, put the imported range to a macro variable and execute `proc import` again with proper `RANGE=` definition.

   ```
       %let range=;
       proc sql noprint;
           select A into :range
           from work.x;
       quit;
       %let range = %sysfunc(compress(&range.,$,));
       %put &range.;
       /* resolves to: B2:B4 */

       %macro import(x);
           PROC IMPORT DATAFILE="C:\test.xlsx" DBMS=xlsx out=work.y
              replace;
              getnames=no;
              RANGE="Sheet1$&x.";
           RUN;
       %mend;
       %import(&range.);
   ```

Comment: That could be one potential workaround of many, though I was hoping I could stick to something more straightforward.